# Linker error when using template class with a reference non-type template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, linker, c++14, non-type

I am developing a C++ library where I need to provide class template to the user.

The template parameter of this class is a reference. However, I am getting a linker error. Here is a minimal test case:

test.hh

```
#ifndef TEST_HH_
#define TEST_HH_

template <double const& val>
struct A{};

constexpr double zero = 0.;

A<zero> foo();

#endif // TEST_HH_
```

test.cpp

```
#include "test.hh"

A<zero> foo(){ return A<zero>(); }
```

main.cpp

```
#include "test.hh"

int main()
{
    foo();
}
```

When compiling this piece of code, I get the warning:

```
'A<zero> foo()' used but never defined
```

followed by a linker error:

```
undefined reference to foo()
```

I tried to replace the double by an int :

```
template <int val>
struct A{};
```

and it linked (when passing a `int` as parameter ofc), but I really need a `double`.

I also tried a common solution when a template class involves linkage error, I implemented the `foo()` function in `test.hh` instead of `test.cpp`, but I would like to avoid just putting all the code in the header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be happy that this didn't link! Could be worse...

The problem is basically that `test.cpp` and `main.cpp` both have *different* objects named `::zero`. This is an ODR violation - you have multiple definitions for that variable, and you end up with `A<zero>` technically being different types since `A`'s template parameter `val` is a reference to different objects in different translation units.

Hopefully that explanation makes it clear why `A<int>` works fine.

In C++17, you want:

```
inline constexpr double zero = 0.;
```

In C++14, you either need to add a definition in one of the translation units or do some other kind of magic, like having `::zero` itself be a reference to some static template variable or other voodoo.

Comment: Oh my god it WORKS ! Let's migrate to cpp 17 :) Thank you very much. I thought that variables at global scope or in namespace had external linkage by default. (Yes that explains for int, because I dont declare any variable, i did A<1> in both files so the values was the same).

Comment: @Baxlan It does have external linkage - that's not the issue.

Comment: Doesn't external linkage mean that the variable has only one definition in all translation units ?

Comment: @Baxlan er, sorry, I got that wrong. Namespace scope is internal linkage. It's adding the `inline` that makes it external.